# Error while bootstrapping on VMware

Tags: juju, vmware

I'm trying to bootstrap a VMware controller. My Juju version is 2.2.2-xenial-amd64. Cloud and credential properties seem to be correct. Everything seems to be kinda okay, until the bootstrap process is trying to connect with the controller. From what I see by browsing through the GO code, it tries to contact the API, and that's where it fails. See the output below ...

```
root@gregoryjuju:~/.local/share/juju# juju bootstrap --config ~/.juju/config --model-default ~/.juju/config ilabt ilabtctrl
Creating Juju controller "ilabtctrl" on ilabt/ILABT Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.2 for amd64 Launching controller instance(s) on ilabt/ILABT...
 - downloading http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/server/releases/xenial/release-20170815.1/ubuntu-16.04-server-clo
 - juju-386170-0 (arch=amd64 mem=3.5G) mg.vmdk: 99.05% (27.8MiB/s) 
Fetching Juju GUI 2.8.0 
Waiting for address 
Attempting to connect to 10.10.10.203:22 
Attempting to connect to fe80::250:56ff:feb1:3f32:22 
Bootstrap agent now started 
Contacting Juju controller at 10.10.10.203 to verify accessibility... 
ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden
```

I'm able to contact the GUI (telnet 10.10.10.203 17070) from the same machine I'm bootstrapping the controller.

Somebody any ideas? Already big thanks.

-- small edit with `--debug` flag on --

```
09:56:03 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:842 error dialing websocket: Forbidden
09:56:03 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:492 unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden
09:56:03 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:493 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:115: unable to contact api server after 1 attempts} {github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:39: } {github.com/juju/juju/juju/api.go:72: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:196: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:615: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:739: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:843: unable to connect to API} {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:867: } {Forbidden}])
```

Comment: Do you have http_proxy (or https_proxy) set in your environment? That error looks like it's coming from a proxy, rather than Juju. You may need to set no_proxy, or clear http(s)_proxy for the bootstrap process.

Comment: On which machine? The machine I initiated the bootstrap from (1) or the machine with the controller (2)? On (1) I've set the proxy settings (to the best of my knowledge). apt and wget both work. On (2) I first used the juju config file to set the proxy settings, but It seemed these settings  didn't trickle down to the machine. So, next I logged into (2) and did everything manually. However, still no success.

Comment: OK, @axw your were correct. Proxy related. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: please flag an answer that solves this, I am having the same issue now.