# is it possible to be using a kvm instance managed by MaaS as a juju bootstrap node?

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization

background:
in the end i want to run kubernetes on a bunch of virtual machines.
to have some automation im trying to leverage the pxe-setup of maas.
it looks like juju is a good way to setup kubernetes.
also juju seems to synergize well with maas.

so i want to bootstrap juju on maas-managed virtualmachine.
the maas part (allocating+pxe boot+os setup) works, but when juju starts working on the machine i get the following error in /var/log/juju/machine-0.log

```
2018-12-03 11:02:00 WARNING juju.cmd.jujud machine.go:831 determining kvm support: INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
: exit status 1
```

the kvm machine doesn't support nested virtualization, so it seems that juju tries to start a kvm vm on my vm, and this can't work and fails.

EDIT:

apparently the answer to my title question is yes.

Comment: I don't follow your description very much. Do you mean "use a kvm instance managed by MaaS as a juju bootstrap node"? If yes, my setup is in this way and works pretty well. May you provide more details e.g. your distribution and how do you setup your MaaS node?

Comment: i mean exactly that! apparently the warning i found is not the cause of my fail. appraenlty i didnt wait long enough... now it seems the juju client can't connect to the controller because of a tls error so i cleared the .local/share/juju directory and tried again..will update as soon as i get new results..

Comment: my bootstrap command now fails after 'contacting juju controller at 172.27.30.146 to verify accessibility...' with 'ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: Forbidden'

Comment: so my mistake is not fully understanding what the http-proxy and apt-proxy parameters do.. if anybody else is having similar problems see https://askubuntu.com/questions/953079/error-while-bootstrapping-on-vmware

Comment: so solution was to set the bootstrapped host in no_proxy on the juju-client host